# Scrapy: Is it possible to compare all items after the spider has finished?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to grab items with important data.  I can use item pipelines to clean the item as it comes in.  But is it possible after the spider is finished to compare all of the items before exporting it to a database?

Comment: It is technically possible from an item pipeline method that is call when the spider has finished, but it may be cleaner to keep that part out of Scrapy.

Comment: Do you think that would work if multiple spiders used to grab the items were on scrapinghub? Is it possible to link spiders together like that on scrapinghub? Then take all the items and compare them?

Comment: If you are using Scrapy Cloud, you can use python-scrapinghub to access the items of one spider from another. You can write spiders (or, probably better, plain scripts) that read items from one or more other crawl jobs and do something with them, such as sending them to a database or other storage system.

Comment: Would I just have to run those script on my computer or a server or can that be done on scraping hub?

Comment: Scrapy Cloud also supports running scripts.

Comment: Awesome I will give that a try!